# Can focus-within exclude certain elements?

Tags: html, css

I've got a stepper component like this

[image: stepper component no focus]

Note the DOM is something like

```html
<div class="my-stepper">
   <button>-</button>
   <input type='number' />
   <button>+</button>
</div>
```

I was using `.my-stepper:focus-within` to ensure that the whole stepper looks focused when you're in the the input

[image: stepper component focus on container only]

But I don't like that when you focus a button, you end up with a doubled up focus

[image]

I was hoping to use something like `.my-stepper:focus-within:not(button:focus)` to ensure that if the focus is on the input, container should look focused, but if focus is on a button, the container should NOT look focused.

[image: stepper component button focus, no focus on cotainer]

How can I get the effect I'm looking for without changing my DOM?

Comment: Add a working HTML+CSS snippet please. We don't know how your CSS looks so we can only make assumptions.

Comment: Btw, no. Is not possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`:has()` should give you what you want. Though keep in mind the browser support isn't 100% currently. But I think this falls nicely under progressive enhancement.

[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:has)

```css
.my-stepper:focus-within {
  outline: 1;
}

.my-stepper:has(button:focus) {
  outline: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

consider extracting your buttons outside of container. This will let you focus within stepper only:

```css
.box {
position: relative;
width: 100px;
}
.btn-layer {
top:0;
position: absolute;
}
.minus {
left: 0;
}
.plus {
right: 0
}

input {
width: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="my-stepper">
     <input type='number' />
  </div>
  <div class="btn-layer">
         <button class="minus">-</button>
         <button class="plus">+</button>
  </div>
</div>
```